# How to make an Android 4.0.3 x86 virtual device in tablet form?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

The new x86 support for the Android 4.0.3 emulator was just released the other day. I've been able to successfully create a new virtual device using the new Intel x86 build and it works great! What a huge difference hardware acceleration makes... The only thing is that I would like to create a VD that behaves like a tablet. I was able to create a tablet sized VD but it displays as if it is the smartphone version of the Android OS.

[image: My AVD setup attempting to create a tablet-sized display.]

Notice that the resulting VD is a smartphone and not a tablet.

[image]

How do I create a tablet version of Android 4.0.3? Thanks.

Comment: WXGA800 isn't in the Built-in Skin drop-down?

Comment: It is actually in the drop-down and that works. Thanks Mark :) I guess I can't use a custom resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to copy **WXGA800** skin folder from API-13 folder (inside SDK) and paste to API-15's skin folder.

For more info, read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/RG2jiZHCIYI)

Comment: Turns out that I had to just use the WXGA800 that was in the drop-down instead of creating my own custom resolution. I'll mark this as the correct answer.